Rolling 12 week average calculation
I would like a calculation that give me a rolling 12 weeks average, I will continue to add to the sheet and want it to automatically update the average as more dates are added. Thanks!
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JbVvyM4pTSLpmAuFOBJbg64AqNrKmqS5jPTyIPDC6eA/edit#gid=0
I used "counta" but not sure the best way to make it dynamic.

To complete, one other option to do it :
=ROUND(COUNTA(FLATTEN(QUERY(A1:F;"select Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6 order by Col1 desc limit 12";0)))/12;2)

You use QUERY to select the rows of the last 12 weeks (data is sorted by descending order "Week"). Then, FLATTEN the output to COUNT the number of values ("A" & "B") and compute your indicator.


Use filter(), like this:
=let( 
  rollWeeks, 12, 
  data, filter(B2:F, isnumber(A2:A), A2:A > max(A2:A) - rollWeeks), 
  averageTotal, counta(data) / rollWeeks, 
  averageA, countif(data, "A") / rollWeeks, 
  vstack(averageTotal, averageA)  
)

See
let(),
filter()
and
vstack().

Hmm, this did not work in my sheet - can you check here and see what calc you would use? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JbVvyM4pTSLpmAuFOBJbg64AqNrKmqS5jPTyIPDC6eA/edit#gid=0

The formula seems to work fine when pasted in cell J8. It outputs a spilled result that goes in cells J8:J9. Cell J9 must be blank so that there is room for the result.
